# My code works, gives me correct output, but I also get extra numbers

Tags: arrays, pointers, c89

I made a program that would take two arrays, and place into into a function that will compare the elements of both arrays, and create a new array that has all the unique elements from the first 2. My code compiles w/o errors, and when I run the code, i get the correct output, however I get a bunch of extra random numbers over all size following after. I'm not sure if it is some sort of segmentation-fault, or something else. But i'm not sure what this problem is related to and where to look for a solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void find_elements(int *a, int n1, int *b, int n2, int *c, int *size);

int main(){

int n1, n2;
int a[n1];
int b[n2];
int i;
int size=0;

printf("Enter the length of the first array: ");
scanf("%d", &n1);


printf("Enter the elements of the first array: ");
for(i=0; i<n1; i++)
scanf("%d", &a[i]);

printf("Enter the length of the second array: ");
scanf("%d", &n2);


printf("enter the elements of the second array: ");
for(i=0; i<n2; i++)
scanf("%d", &b[i]);

size = n1+n2;
int c[size];

  find_elements(a, n1, b, n2, c, &size);
printf("Output: ");
for(i=0; i<(size); i++)
printf("%d ", c[i]);


return 0;
```

}

```
void find_elements(int *a, int n1, int *b, int n2, int *c, int *size){

int *p;
int *p1;
int i, j;
int count;

p=a;

for(i=0; i<n1; i++){
    p1 = b;
    for(j=0; j<n2; j++){
        if(*p==*p1){
            break;}
        p1++;
            }
    if(j==n2){
        *c=*p;
        c++;
        count++;
        }
    p++;
```

}

```
p=b;

for(i=0; i<n2; i++){
    p1 = a;
    for(j=0; j<n1; j++){
            if(*p==*p1){
            break;}
        p1++;
            }
    if(j==n1){
        *c=*p;
        c++;
        count++;
        }
    p++;
    *size = count;
```

}
}

Input/Output Example for my code:

Enter the length of the first array: 5

Enter the elements of the array: 9 8 5 6 4

Enter the length of the second array: 4

Enter the elements of the array: 6 9 7 1

Output: 8 5 4 7 1

I get this output, but in addition i get this:

Output: 8 5 4 7 1 0 -1 0 0 0 740434312 60 0 0 4196006 0 6 7 9 1 9 8 5 6 4 0 4196528 65 4 5 -1 -1 1000611008 32764 -1 -1 1000610992 32764 8 0 1000610928 32764 4195408 43 0 0 4195408 0 0 0 746712

Comment: I don’t see `count` initialized anywhere. Are you compiling with all warnings enabled?

Comment: Oh my, that's exactly it, thank you. I have it set to default warnings, I've gotten warnings for un-initialized variables before weird. Thank you again though.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with the code is the sequence:

```
int n1, n2;
int a[n1];
int b[n2];
```

You allocating array `a` and `b` with uninitialized values, i.e., `n1` and `n2` are unknown at the start of your program.

The other problem is that `int count;` in `find_elements` is also uninitialized. Thus the return value for the output parameter `size` is undefined.

A memory *safer* (not safe) version of `main` could look like:

```
int main() {
    printf("Enter the length of the first array: ");
    int n1;
    scanf("%d", &n1);

    int *a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * n1);

    printf("Enter the elements of the first array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    printf("Enter the length of the second array: ");
    int n2;
    scanf("%d", &n2);

    int*b=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n2);

    printf("enter the elements of the second array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);

    int size = n1 + n2;

    int *c = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)* size);

    find_elements(a, n1, b, n2, c, &size);
    printf("Output: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < (size); i++)
        printf("%d ", c[i]);

    free(c);
    free(b);
    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```